# Changing Timezone using timedatectl on a read only filesystem

Tags: systemd, readonly, yocto

I am trying to change timezone using timedatectl on a readonly file system. And I am unable to do so. I get an error saying unable to change timezone. I am guessing that is because it is a read-only file system and it has to do with these three files in `/etc`

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    10 Jul 17 21:48 timezone
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    29 Jul 17 21:48 localtime -> /usr/share/zoneinfo/Universal
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    15 Aug 14 22:08 timestamp
```

Should I just create a symlink for `timezone` and `timestamp` ?

I am currently looking at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-system-settings/+bug/1227520

I think they are facing somewhat similar situation. But they are suggesting to create a symlink of /etc/localtime as well. Which I don’t understand?

Any help and pointers would be appreciated?

I am using embedded linux environment for raspberrypi-cm3 poky warrior branch

Comment: If your `/etc` is on a read only filesystem you won't be able to adjust the symbolic link. It would be nice to know what your OS is and why you're trying to adjust timezone. For newly run applications using the `TZ` environment could be what you're looking for.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I have embedded linux environment for Raspberrypi cm3 version 4.19. I am using yocto poky warrior branch. Can you please elaborate on TZ environement

Comment: First hit in Google, have you even tried Googling? https://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/TZ-Variable.html

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Wow. Gee thanks. All my problems solved.And how does that document solve my issue. If you can't help then please don't comment. Have you ever thought that the reason some people might be posting here as a last resolve for help. And instead of helping you have a comment like "Have you hit google".

Comment: You haven't let anyone know what your issue is. Are you trying to change the TZ for your entire device? Does it run NTP and you can run `date` to fix its time? Running apps this way `TZ=SomeTimeZone appname` will run them the required time zone. I'm not sure why you're so exasperated.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I thought the issue was clear. I am sorry if its not, I am trying to change the timezone on my device which is a raspberrypi-Cm3. When I run the command `timedatectl set-timezone "America\New_York"` I get an error saying Failed to set timezone read-only file system. So I want to know how to change my timezone using `timedatectl` on a read-only rootfs. Or how do people change timezone on read-only file system?

Comment: If your kernel supports any overlay fs, mount it and you'll be able to overwrite any files. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aufs#See_also